# Flex slider not working in mobile devices

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I am using flex slider in my site to show image slider. It is working fine in desktop. Since flex slider is a responsive one, It is not working in mobile device. I checked with callback after and before, when i click the navigation arrow, I can get the callback reponse.

```
        $(window).load(function(){
        $('#carousel').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            slideDirection: "horizontal", 
            animationLoop: true,
            slideshow: false,
            itemWidth: 263,
            itemMargin: 35,
            move:1,
            asNavFor: '#slider',
            touch: true,
            after: function(){
                console.log('Navigation arrow clicked');
            }
        });});
```

Comment: may be duplicate check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752098/flex-slider-is-not-working-on-mobile-phones

Comment: I checked the slider in the site, that is not a responsive slider. My slider is responsive. I tried the solution that question. But no luck. @rJ7